How do I replace the main network interface with a bridge on GCP?
What I'm trying to do is launch a bridged OpenVPN server on GCP (in a GCE VM). What looks like a crucial part to me is in the title. If I succeed, the rest is supposedly easy. I tried two approaches:

The Arch Linux way... the iproute2 way actually. I asked about it on the Arch Linux forum. The details are  in a gist.
The OpenVPN way... the bridge-utils way actually. Based on the script from the official howto. The details are in a gist.

It looks like it's not possible to do it on GCP, or am I missing something? Which is it? Or what can I do to further investigate the issue?

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

resource "google_compute_instance" "test-bridge" {
  name = "test-bridge"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone = "europe-central2-a"
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-12"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.test-bridge.self_link
    access_config {}
  }
  metadata = {
    enable-oslogin = true
    startup-script = <<-SCRIPT
      cat <<EOF >> /etc/netplan/90-default.yaml
          bridges:
              br0:
                  dhcp4: yes
                  interfaces:
                      - all-en
                  macaddress: `cat /sys/class/net/ens4/address`
      EOF
      netplan apply
    SCRIPT
  }
}

More details in the following gists.

You are absolutely right. Replacing the main network interface with a bridge on GCP for a bridged OpenVPN server setup is not recommended and it can lead to unexpected behavior and potential security issues.
You can try the below approaches for implementing a bridged OpenVPN server on GCP:

Take into consideration by utilizing Google Cloud VPN, a managed VPN service that provides remote and site-to-site VPN connectivity. This makes use of Google's secure network architecture and does away with the requirement for you to run a dedicated OpenVPN server.

Create a custom virtual private network (VPN) and set up firewall rules to permit open VPN connections in the GCP console. In this VPN, you can set up an open VPN server inside a virtual machine. Although it calls for cautious network administration, this helps to provide additional control over the OpenVPN configuration.

Additionally, You can also explore Third party OpenVPN solutions available on GCP. This could ease the process by providing predefined templates and automatic deployments.


EDIT
The recommended approaches don't directly involve bridging .But they provide secure and reliable ways to achieve similar functionality.
Bridging and tunneling used by cloud VPN are different network technologies.Cloud VPN offers a safe tunnel connection that functions similarly to bridging but with enhanced network security.
Refer to the document on How to Setup OpenVPN Server on Google Cloud Platform.

You're saying that I'm absolutely right, but I said replacing the main NIC seems impossible, you're saying it's not recommended. But then you say "approaches for implementing a bridged OpenVPN server on GCP." And the first approach is to use Cloud VPN with OpenVPN's Access Server. What does it have to do with bridging? In #2 you supposedly suggest to launch OpenVPN server (where? how?). Should it be running in bridged mode? If so, how do I make it work? If not, what does it have to do with bridging? And in #3 you again suggest Access Server. And again, what does it have to do with bridging?

@x-yuri, I have edited my answer and sorry for the confusion in the previous response.I hope this clarification helps! If you have any further questions about specific approaches or security considerations, feel free to ask.

What exactly is wrong with the bridged mode?

As you know, Security should always be a top priority when configuring your network infrastructure.  Using a bridged mode for an OpenVPN  server on GCP might give you security risks in the  managed network environment. GCP offers a managed network with its own routing and security mechanisms. But bridging can disrupt these mechanisms and lead to unexpected network behaviour. Also bridging gives an additional layer of complexity to the network configuration.
